# How to display spin result after each spinning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this spinning code:

```js
var spinCount = 0;

function myfunction() {
  if (spinCount > 3) {
    alert("No more Spins");
    return false;
  }
  var x = 1024; //min value
  var y = 9999; // max value

  var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;

  document.getElementById('box').style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";

  var element = document.getElementById('mainbox');
  element.classList.remove('animate');

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add('animate');
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 second
  spinCount++;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(60, 60, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 245, 230, 1) 52%, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.mainbox:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('../img/arrow-wheel.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 32px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 5s;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.span1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 92%, 100% 50%, 0 8%);
  background-color: #fffb00;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

.span2 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 92%, 0 50%, 100% 8%);
  background-color: #ff4fa1;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.span3 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 8% 100%, 92% 100%);
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.span4 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 92% 0, 8% 0);
  background-color: #22ff00;
  top: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.box1 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-270deg);
}

.box1 .span1 b,
.box2 .span1 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(185deg);
}

.box2 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.box1 .span4 b,
.box2 .span4 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-85deg);
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

span b {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #001aff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin:active {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainbox.animate:after {
  animation: animateArrow 0.7s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animateArrow {
  50% {
    right: -40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <div class="box1">
      <span class="span1"><b>$10</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$20</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$30</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$40</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <span class="span1"><b>$50</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$60</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$70</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$80</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="spin" onclick="myfunction()">SPIN</button>
</div>
```

Now I want to put something like an indicator and show user the result at the end of each spinning.

Like, the user might spin and get $10, I want to show the user that he has gotten $10 from the spin maybe below the wheel.

This image below best explain what I am trying to explain.
[image]

Comment: If this is *not* a homework/practice assignment and will be used "real-world" then you should probably get the result server-side and store it server-side with the UI only displaying the result.  Otherwise user can open console and enter: `$("#mainbox >div > div > span > b").text("$10000000")`

Comment: I will store it in database. even if user alter it, it is as good as nothing because only him is seeing it.

Comment: if I get the code to display it, I will store it in server end before I render to UI

Comment: The idea I have is checking wich text div is closest to a 270° rotation. Something like `#box`  rotation%270 - `b` rotation

Comment: put let me see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :).

What I did was added a while loop that subtracted 360 from `deg` until i got a number between 0 and 360.  I then did some simple math knowing that your spinner has 8 different spinner positions, thats 45 degrees per section and seeing that it always started in the middle of $40, I was able to work out a series of if statements in js to figure out where the spinner landed on.

I also added div `<div id="line"></div>` to make like a little arrow thingy to show where the spinner landed on. Take a look here:

```js
var spinCount = 0;
function myfunction() {
  if (spinCount > 3) {
    alert("No more Spins");
    return false;
  }
  var x = 1024; //min value
  var y = 9999; // max value
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = ""; 
  var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;

  document.getElementById('box').style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)"; 
  var element = document.getElementById('mainbox');
  element.classList.remove('animate');


  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add('animate');
    
    while (deg >= 360) {
  deg = deg - 360;
}
  
  if (deg >= 337 || deg < 22)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $40"; 
  }
  if (deg >= 22 && deg < 67)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $60"; 
  }
  if (deg >= 67 && deg < 112)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $10"; 
  }
  if (deg >= 112 && deg < 157)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $80"; 
  }
  if (deg >= 157 && deg < 202)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $30"; 
  }
  if (deg >= 202 && deg < 247)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $50"; 
  }  
  if (deg >= 247 && deg < 292)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $20"; 
  }
  if (deg >= 292 && deg < 337)
  {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Congratulations you have won $70"; 
  }
    
    
    
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 second
  

  
  
  spinCount++;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(60, 60, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 245, 230, 1) 52%, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.mainbox:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('../img/arrow-wheel.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 32px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 5s;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.span1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 92%, 100% 50%, 0 8%);
  background-color: #fffb00;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

.span2 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 92%, 0 50%, 100% 8%);
  background-color: #ff4fa1;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.span3 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 8% 100%, 92% 100%);
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.span4 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 92% 0, 8% 0);
  background-color: #22ff00;
  top: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.box1 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-270deg);
}

.box1 .span1 b,
.box2 .span1 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(185deg);
}

.box2 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.box1 .span4 b,
.box2 .span4 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-85deg);
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

span b {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #001aff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin:active {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainbox.animate:after {
  animation: animateArrow 0.7s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animateArrow {
  50% {
    right: -40px;
  }
}


#line {
  position: absolute;
  top 0;
  right: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 3px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

#output {
  text-align:center;  
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
  <div id="line"></div>
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <div class="box1">
      <span class="span1"><b>$10</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$20</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$30</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$40</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <span class="span1"><b>$50</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$60</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$70</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$80</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="spin" onclick="myfunction()">SPIN</button>
  
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to determine the top paddle position. Half the paddles have the smaller width value. This group contains the top paddle. Among that group the paddle having the smallest y coordinate is the topmost paddle in the group.

All paddle elements are collected using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which is converted to an array [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and looped using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

A multidimensional array is is populated with the paddle `textContent`, width, and y coordinate. The array is sorted, first by the width, then the y coordinate. This puts the topmost paddle at the top of the array. The paddle dollar amount can be accessed at `paddles[0][0]`.

```
function getSpin() {
  let paddles = [];
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="span"]')).forEach(function(paddle) {
    let gbcr = paddle.getBoundingClientRect();
    paddles.push([paddle.textContent, Math.round(gbcr.width), Math.round(gbcr.y)]);
  });
  return paddles.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[1] > b[1]) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a[1] < b[1]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a[2] < b[2]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[2] > b[2]) {
      return 1;
    }
  })[0][0];
}
```

A message `div` is added below the `button`:

```
<button class="spin" onclick="myfunction()">SPIN</button>

<div id="spinresult">Click "SPIN" to play.</div>
```

...and the winning message is determined then written to it within the `setTimeout` function, which is in the `myFunction` function.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  element.classList.add('animate');
  document.querySelector('#spinresult').textContent = `Congratulations, you've won ${getSpin()}!`;
}, 5000); //5000 = 5 second
```

The arrow down pointer is displayed using a `div` placed before the spin box and styled using CSS.

```
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div id="box" class="box">
```

```js
var spinCount = 0;

function myfunction() {
  if (spinCount > 3) {
    alert("No more Spins");
    return false;
  }
  var x = 1024; //min value
  var y = 9999; // max value

  var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;

  document.getElementById('box').style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";

  var element = document.getElementById('mainbox');
  element.classList.remove('animate');

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add('animate');
    document.querySelector('#spinresult').textContent = `Congratulations, you've won ${getSpin()}!`;
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 second
  spinCount++;

  function getSpin() {
    let paddles = [];
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="span"]')).forEach(function(paddle) {
      let gbcr = paddle.getBoundingClientRect();
      paddles.push([paddle.textContent, Math.round(gbcr.width), Math.round(gbcr.y)]);
    });
    return paddles.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a[1] > b[1]) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a[1] < b[1]) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a[2] < b[2]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[2] > b[2]) {
        return 1;
      }
    })[0][0];
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(60, 60, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 245, 230, 1) 52%, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainbox:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('../img/arrow-wheel.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 32px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 5s;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.span1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 92%, 100% 50%, 0 8%);
  background-color: #fffb00;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

.span2 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 92%, 0 50%, 100% 8%);
  background-color: #ff4fa1;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.span3 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 8% 100%, 92% 100%);
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.span4 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 92% 0, 8% 0);
  background-color: #22ff00;
  top: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.box1 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-270deg);
}

.box1 .span1 b,
.box2 .span1 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(185deg);
}

.box2 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.box1 .span4 b,
.box2 .span4 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-85deg);
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

span b {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #001aff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin:active {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainbox.animate:after {
  animation: animateArrow 0.7s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animateArrow {
  50% {
    right: -40px;
  }
}

#spinresult {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.arrow-down::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  content: "";
  border-top: 1em solid red;
  border-left: 1em solid transparent;
  border-right: 1em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <div class="box1">
      <span class="span1"><b>$10</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$20</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$30</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$40</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <span class="span1"><b>$50</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$60</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$70</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$80</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="spin" onclick="myfunction()">SPIN</button>

  <div id="spinresult">Click "SPIN" to play.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@john 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73734123/2743458)...

Using the random degree value and the Javascript [remain operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) `%` to get the spin wheel range the degree value falls in: `1-45, 46-90, 91-135, 136-180, 181-225, 226-270, 271-315, 316-360`.

Since the wheel starts at a 22 degree offset, i.e., the top paddle is centered, the degree range value must be adjusted by subtracting 21 degrees after it is calculated.

With the adjusted range value, the portion of the wheel—which paddle—can be determined by dividing it by 45 degrees and rounding down. This (usually) provides 0 - 7 which corresponds to the array of `win` array values. However, in the case of degree range below 22, -1 is returned and that is adjusted to index 7.

```js
let spinCount = 0;
let [xx, yy] = [1024, 9999]; // [min, max]
let win = ["$60", "$10", "$80", "$30", "$50", "$20", "$70", "$40"];

document.querySelector('.spin').addEventListener('click', spin);

function spin() {
  if (spinCount > 3) {
    alert("No more spins.");
    return false;
  }
  let deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (xx - yy)) + yy;
  let deg_off = (deg % 360) - 21;
  let widx = Math.floor((deg_off / 45));
  widx = (0 <= widx) ? widx : 7;

  document.getElementById('box').style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
  let mainbox = document.getElementById('mainbox');
  mainbox.classList.remove('animate');

  setTimeout(function() {
    mainbox.classList.add('animate');
    document.getElementById("winnings").textContent 
      = `Congratulations, you've won ${win[widx]}`;
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 second

  spinCount++;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(60, 60, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 245, 230, 1) 52%, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainbox:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('../img/arrow-wheel.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 32px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 5s;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.span1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 92%, 100% 50%, 0 8%);
  background-color: #fffb00;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

.span2 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 92%, 0 50%, 100% 8%);
  background-color: #ff4fa1;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.span3 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 8% 100%, 92% 100%);
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.span4 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 92% 0, 8% 0);
  background-color: #22ff00;
  top: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.box1 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-270deg);
}

.box1 .span1 b,
.box2 .span1 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(185deg);
}

.box2 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.box1 .span4 b,
.box2 .span4 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-85deg);
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

span b {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #001aff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin:active {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainbox.animate:after {
  animation: animateArrow 0.7s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animateArrow {
  50% {
    right: -40px;
  }
}

#winnings {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.arrow-down::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.35em;
  content: "";
  border-top: 1em solid red;
  border-left: 1em solid transparent;
  border-right: 1em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <div class="box1">
      <span class="span1"><b>$10</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$20</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$30</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$40</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <span class="span1"><b>$50</b></span>
      <span class="span2"><b>$60</b></span>
      <span class="span3"><b>$70</b></span>
      <span class="span4"><b>$80</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="spin">SPIN</button>
  <div id="winnings">Click "SPIN" to play.</div>

</div>
```